# Add opaque overlay to element

Tags: jquery, css

I have been asked to display some numbers in a certain way - see image:

[image]

As you can see in the image, I need some sort of grey overlay on the upper half of each number to make part of the font a little darker. (At least, adding a semi transparent overlay is how I imagine this could be solved.)

I get these numbers in from one single xml node, and split the numbers with this piece of script:

```
var text = $("div.balance_number span");
var characters = $("div.balance_number").text().split("");
$("div.balance_number").empty();
$.each(characters, function (i, el) {
    $("div.balance_number").append("<span>" + el + "</span")
});
$("div.balance_number span").each(function (index) {
    var pt = $(this).text();
    if (pt == ",") {
        $(this).addClass("empty")
    }
});
```

The result is shown in the fiddle below. How do I solve the task of adding a overlay to the numbers? Or could it be solved in another way?

I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyuHb/1/).

Comment: Could you create the little square an apply this kind of css on them: `background-color:#FFF; opacity:0.2;` ?

Comment: I'd look at using web fonts for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm asking for... I just don't know how it  can be done with the script.

Comment: For example _without_ JavaScript, using CSS generated content: http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/tyuHb/4/

Comment: It's a quick cheat, but from that image it looks like you could just add some semi-transparent, absolutely positioned (`top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%;`) pseudo elements as an overlay to each number set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tyuHb/5/

```html
<div class="balance">
    <div class="balance_number">
        <span><span></span>9</span>
        <span><span></span>5</span>
        <span class="empty">,</span>
        <span><span></span>3</span>
        <span><span></span>5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.balance_number > span {         /* note the ">" */
    position:relative;
    /* all other code ...*/
```

and:

```css
.balance_number span > span {    /* note the ">" */
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height:24px;
    width:30px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the live code you'll be working with, you could try something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/tyuHb/7/)?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="balance">
  <div class="balance_number">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="dark-left"></div>  
        <span>9</span>
        <span>5</span>
    </div>
    <span class="empty">,</span>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="dark-right"></div>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.left, .right {
    position: relative;
    width: 62px;
    float: left;
}
.dark-left, .dark-right {
    width: 62px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: I might try this as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Meek Roko's answer is cleaner and better, use his :o)